# Codigo ajax no escribe en base de datos

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Quiero mandar cierta informacion a mi base de datos. Hasta el momento tengo este codigo el cual lo divido en 2 partes, la primera es la parte de javascript y la segunda de PHP.

```
function notas(){
            
            var a = new XHMLHttpRequest();
            var url = "notas.php";
            var texto = document.getElementById("nota").value;
            var vars = "nota="+texto;
            
            a.open("POST", url, true);
            a.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            a.send(vars);
            
        }
```

notas.php...

```
<?php
    require("conexion.php");
    
    $nota = $_POST["nota"];
    $fecha = date("m/d/Y");
    $escribir = "INSERT INTO notas(fecha, nota) VALUES('".$fecha."','".$nota."')";
    
    mysqli_query($conexion, $escribir);

    $conexion->close();
?>
```

y ademas agrego la parte del html...

```
<div id="notas">
        <label>Nueva nota: </label>
        <input id="nota" name="nota" type="text" />
        <button type="submit" onclick="notas()" id="boton-guardar-nota">guardar</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Te faltó realizar el envío: `a.send(vars);`.

Comment: ¿como hago eso?

Comment: Añade esa línea en la función `notas`. Tú lo haces en la función del evento `onreadystatechange`, pero ese evento nunca va a ocurrir si no haces el envío por fuera.

Comment: ya lo cambie y sigue sin funcionar. Alguna otra observacion que tengas?

Comment: Actualiza el código en tu pregunta para analizarlo.

Comment: Listo, a parte tambien agregue el html por si hay algun erro ahi.

Answer (score 0):

En el código JS recepciona la respuesta del servidor una vez completada la petición.

```
a.addEventListener("load", function(){
    if (this.status == 200){
        alert(this.responseText);
    }
}, false);
```

Y en el código PHP imprime una respuesta una vez ejecutada la sentencia SQL.

```
echo mysqli_query($conexion, $escribir) ? 'Ok' : 'Error: ' . mysqli_error($conexion);
```

Si todo marcha bien, aparecerá una alerta con el texto "Ok", de lo contrario, se indicará un mensaje de "Error". Si no sucede nada, revisa en la herramienta para desarrolladores de tu navegador web (F12 > Network > Clic en el nombre del archivo PHP > Response) si el archivo PHP está devolviendo algún error.